# Как правильно хранить отдельный HTML шаблон?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно хранить HTML шаблоны так чтобы в определенный момент их можно было взять и подключить к странице с помощью jS.
Можно определять HTML прямо в js файле так чтобы функция возвращала нужный компонент, но кажется это не очень красиво. В процессе поиска решения наткнулся на

```
<template>
```

и html импорты, но как-то не обнаружил надежных свидетельств того, что какой-то из этих способов активно используется.
Хотелось бы получить какой-то Best practice пример того как это принято делать. т.к. приложение не большое и клиентского кода не очень много, хотелось бы решение  на чистом javascript или с использованием какой-нибудь очень легковесной и специализированной библиотеки.

Comment: mustache или что-то типа того?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите прям простое и отдельное, то можно попробовать [jQuery Template Plugin](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) или [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender). Помимио документации статьи гугляться очень просто.

Так же можно посмотреть на более сложные и мощные шаблонизаторы вроде [Jade](http://jade-lang.com), [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) или [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js). Но для них нужна сборка через Gulp/Grunt/Webpack

В основном сейчас все пишут с фреймворками и их шаблонами, например AngularJs, VueJs или библиотеками ReactJs

Пример кода с JsRender

```
var $ = window.jsrender;
// Можно прямо из строки, например вызывать после завершения AJAX запроса и полученный контент передавать в функцию template()
var tmpl = $.templates("Name: {{:name}}");
```

А можно из шаблонов в тегах `<script>`

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    Name: {{:name}}
</script>
```

Вот так происходит отрисовка шаблона из строки (взят с документации)

```
var tmpl = $.templates(" Name: {{:name}}<br/> ");

var person = {name: "Jim"};

// Render template for person object
var html = tmpl.render(person); // ready for insertion, e.g $("#result").html(html);

// result: "Name: Jim<br/> "
```

Я лично давным давно использовал jQuery Template и работает очень просто, думаю JsRender так же будет работать удобно, но еще и быстрее.